# managing keyboard in ios for number of textfields

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

Everything is fine for me except one case. When I begin editing the textfield, keyboard was shown: method is getting called, but without resigning first one if I edit the next textfield, this method is not getting called.

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification   object:nil];

}


     -(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
      {
      NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
      CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

      UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
      testScroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
     testScroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
       CGRect aRect = self.view.bounds;

      CGPoint activepoint= [active.superview convertPoint:active.frame.origin toView:nil];
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activepoint) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, active.frame.origin.y+active.frame.size.height-kbSize.height+100);// here active is my particular textfields and i an changing it in begin editing method.
        [testScroll setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
```

here my problem is even though i was switching between two text fields my scrollview has to set for particular offset.

thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the keyboardWasShown and keyboardWillBeHidden methods are not called? I believe because the keyboard is never hidden in the first place if you are just switching between text fields.

Comment: @verbumdei then how can i manage the switching between textfields in my case and see my edit